# docker: Dropping packages between containers

Tags: docker, iptables

I have a couple of containers defined in a network, and I need to simulate network outage(temporary) on one of the container.

I was checking the iptable, but could not find a way to
drop e.g. 60% of packages which are going to one of the containers, etc.

Answer (score 0):

it seems netem does what you look for.

See

https://wiki.linuxfoundation.org/networking/netem